# Javascript create event method

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

i have helper class and want to define event method which is fired when some value is changed.

eg simplify:

```
class HelperClass {
  activeIndex = 0;

  constructor(element) {}

  ...some computation methods...
}
```

And i need to fire event when activeIndex is changed from outside. Something like addEventListener. When is internal value changed it could be listen from outside of clas. 
For example:

```
const obj = new HelperClass(element);
obj.onActiveIndexChange((event, activeIndex) => ...something...)

or

obj.on('activeIndexChange', (event, activeIndex) => ....something.... )
```

I don't want to use external libraries. Prefer vanilla code with native features.

Thanks.

UPDATE: SIMPLE SOLUTION

```
class HelperClass {
  activeIndex = 0;

  addEventListener(eventName, func) {
    this[
      `on${eventName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${eventName.substr(1)}`
    ] = func;
  }

  onActiveIndexChange(activeIndex) {}
}
```

this.onActiveIndexChange(newValue) calling after changing value

and then outside defining:

```
objInstance.addEventListener('activeIndexChange', (activeIndex) =>
  ...myCustomCodePassed in callback...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need sometheng line this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

or https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter if you are using NodeJS

Comment: Trying to figure out how to use in my case. My Javascript is not main language and it is quite difficult to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a setter for an object property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty

It would trigger a function every time you change the value.

It is vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: defineProperty is fine when i want to call method from self class, Same functionality like ES6 setter right?. But i want to create method event accessible from outside.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a method!

Comment: I create fast solution. Not best, but works. I made method wchith takes another function and that function i can call from outside. Something like this: onValueChange(func) { this.callbackMethod = func }